# Docker containers unable to connect to each other

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, microservices

I am building a microservice solution using docker compose to run locally.
I'm using .netcore for the services. 
When I run the projects using visual studio everything connects and works fine but when i run in docker i can connect to the services externally but the services are unable to connect to each other.When I inspect in docker everything looks ok and all containers are on the same network. I'm assuming it is some small setting or configuration I'm missing but haven't been able to find anyone with the same issue.

Here's the docker-compose code

```
docker-compose.yml

    version: '3'

services:
  underrule.frontend:
    image: underrule.frontend
    build:
      context: ./UnderRule.FrontEnd
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

  underrule.apigateway:
    image: underrule.apigateway
    build:
      context: ./UnderRule.ApiGateway
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

  underrule.authentication:
    image: underrule.authentication
    build:
      context: ./UnderRule.Authentication
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

  underrule.playerservice:
    image: underrule.playerservice
    build:
      context: ./UnderRule.PlayerService
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

  underrule.registrationservice:
    image: underrule.registrationservice
    build:
      context: ./UnderRule.RegistrationService
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

  underrule.worldservice:
    image: underrule.worldservice
    build:
      context: ./UnderRule.WorldService
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

docker-compose.override.yml

    version: '3'

services:
  underrule.frontend:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "5000:80"

  underrule.apigateway:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "9000:80"

  underrule.authentication:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "5001:80"

  underrule.playerservice:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "5002:80"

  underrule.registrationservice:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "5004:80"

  underrule.worldservice:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "5003:80"

all dockerfiles are basically the same

    FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
    ARG source
    WORKDIR /app
    EXPOSE 80
    COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "UnderRule.ApiGateway.dll"]
```

Any ideas? I've tried messing with the ports without much luck.

I am connecting internally using HttpClient with the path like
http://localhost:{port}

Help is very much appreciated and let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

Within a container, localhost points to the container itself and not the bridged network.

As you are using docker-compose, you should point to the container name defined in docker-compose.yml file (e.g. *underrule.worldservice* -> http://underrule.worldservice:port).

Another way is to point to the docker bridge network ip. On linux this IP is by default 172.17.0.1. On windows it depends on the version of docker you are running you should inspect your configuration (`ipconfig`).